# Prevent bean from being constructed in the spring cloud bootstrap context

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

Annotated spring beans in my spring-cloud application are being created twice. I assume this is because they get constructed into the bootstrap context and then into a child application context.

For me this is undesirable because some are annotated with `@Scheduled` to perform periodic refreshes of the data that they provide from a backend data source and this is happening twice in quick succession once for each context.

If it's not otherwise harmful then can I disable all of the application beans from being created in the bootstrap context? If not then can I detect in code when I'm running in the bootstrap context? I use entirely annotation-based beans with component scanning enabled on the Camden SR4 release.

Comment: Spring Cloud doesn't do any component scanning or anything in bootstrap. So if they are getting created there you did it yourself. A sample would be useful.

Comment: @DaveSyer Have investigated further. This service adds another servlet to perform proxying functionality. The proxy servlet is itself a bean but has a `ServletRegistrationBean` to register it. The second context appears to be created with the new servlet. I'm investigating if it can be created to share the root WebApplicationContext created by spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved this myself. It was down to two different issues in the code and nothing to do with multiple contexts.

Firstly my long held assumption that an `@PostConstruct` method is only ever called once was false. Moving my one-off bean initialisation code to an implementation of `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` solved that one.

Secondly I got bit by multiple initialisation of a bean with an `@Scheduled` annotation causes the scheduler to run multiple times. To be fair, this behaviour is noted in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled). This was easily solved by moving the scheduled task creation to a regular java `ScheduledExecutorService` set up in the `ApplicationReadyEvent` implementation.